# How historically accurate is Josephus?

Tags: minhag, history, books-generally, historical-figures

How accurate is the writing of Josephus? Can we rely on any of his writings to establish authentic Jewish practices or in areas of halacha?

Comment: I feel like those are separate questions.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/fighting-wars-on-shabbat

Comment: @msh210 Books of Jewish History don't count as [tag:jewish-books]?

Comment: @DoubleAA, do they?

Comment: @msh210 Well they're about Jews and Jewish things, often written by Jews, and contain content that most Jews should know something about. Sounds a lot like a Jewish Book.

Comment: @DoubleAA, as always, feel free to edit.

Comment: @msh210 I prefer consensus to edit wars.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44192

Comment: The most obvious inaccuracy in Josephus is the transcription of the last speech made in Masada.  Since everyone inside died, no one knows what they said.

Comment: @Wad Cheber - Josephus says there WERE survivors - women and children who hid during the carnage.  That being said, Josephus DOES continue the tradition of historical writers of his time by placing speeches in the mouths of various figures that emphasize whatever trait he feels appropriate (heroism, mercy, cruelty, etc) to make a better(or worse) storv/reputation of his subject.  A close look at any of those speeches reveals how unlikely they were to be accurate.  That was just the way they wrote history/biographies/etc at that time - custom-tuned for their audience, basically.

Comment: He is very historically accurate. 100%.

Answer (score 6):

[The Shulchan Aruch Harav](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25073&pgnum=450) says that one is allowed to read Josephus on Shabbos as it contains words of "Mussar and Yiras Shamayim".

However, the [Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14946&pgnum=358) says that

> With regards to reliability of Josephus' and precision, many pointed out [the issues], and even thou 'there is much Mussar and Yiras Shamayim' [in his sefer], no one has ever called him "Rabbi Yosef".

The Lubavitcher Rebbe brings an example where his description of the Beis Hamikdash disagreed with the description in the traditional sources.

However, the Lubavitcher Rebbe pointed out that this could have been a mistranslation into Hebrew.

Comment: I didn't know you needed semicha to be a historian.

Comment: With regards to the Shulchan Aruch Harav (and the Bach it is based on), Josephus or Jossipun?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josippon . My guess is that it is referring to Josippon. I can't verify the accuracy of this post, but it is interesting: http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/5723-josephus-and-yosippon/

Comment: @Menachem Yossipun

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: if so, it doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @Menachem that could have been the "mistranslation" to which the Rebbe was referring.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I think the idea is that he was neither a precise historian nor a rabbi.

Comment: But does Flavius Josephus' work have any "Mussar and Yiras Shamayim" in it. This would affect whether you could read it on Shabbat or not.

Comment: How is Josephus (which is Latin) pronounced in Greek?

Comment: The Greek Wikipedia calls him "Iósepos".

Comment: @DoubleAA: From the context of the letter, it seems obvious that the Rebbe was responding to the person referring to Josephus as Rav Yosef, to which the Rebbe responded that putting the discussion of the veracity of his account aside, no one ever refers to Josephus as a Rabbi.

Comment: @DoubleAA part of the question is "Can we rely on any of his writings to establish authentic Jewish practices or in areas of halacha?", which is something we _normally_ require smicha for

Comment: @Rabbi not at all, we require semicha to paskin not to record facts used in paskining

Answer (score 5):

R. Chaim Knoller ([Dvar Yom Beyomo, entry for 17 Iyar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31168&pgnum=117)) comments, regarding Josephus' sympathetic portrayal of Titus, that as a member of the imperial household he was compelled to falsify history in this regard. (He also gives an interesting homiletic rendering of the phrase in [Mikvaos 10:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99_%D7%90), "the inkwell of Yosef the kohen had a hole in its side": it hints at the flaw ("hole") in the writings of Josephus, brought about by his living "at the side" of the Romans.)

Doros Harishonim takes an even more hard-line view. He [argues](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20125&pgnum=48) that Josephus tendentiously rewrote history in order to portray the Jews as uncivilized rebels, and to whitewash the actions of Agrippa II (in his view, Josephus' collaborator in this effort) that provoked the revolt.

Comment: IIRC, Rashi quotes Josephus's history to explain how Sinas Chinam destroyed the Beis HaMikdash. So does Ya'aros Devash by Rav Yonasan Eybeshutz.

Answer (score 0):

Rashi brings him down in arvey pesochim. I think it's daf 119a.