# Josephus' Fall of Jerusalem

Tags: history, jewish-books, beis-hamikdash, churban-destruction

Is this book commonly accepted in the Jewish world as an accurate description of the events surrounding destruction of the Beit HaMikdash?  I'm particularly interested in its portrayal of the behavior of the Jews under siege, since we also have a (damning) Talmudic description of the behavior of the Jews at the time.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16403

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How historically accurate is Josephus?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16403/how-historically-accurate-is-josephus)

Comment: to Gershon Gold: I am aware of the question you cite yet I am specifically interested in Jewish take(s) on the book I cited because Josephus indictment of the Jews defending Jerusalem is devastating - yet I would like to reckon how much credence to give what he says, given that he apparently was working for the Roman regime?  Thank you for your consideration and an easy and meaningful fast to all Yisrael.